# find pre html element with prevUntil jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when user click on span element i must search in the pre row in table for first input element and return number of first row that contain input element inside td. for example span is in the fourth row of the table and first input element is in the second row of the table . in this case when user click on the span element i must return 2 .how i can search to find first input element in the pre row ?

```
<script>
$("span").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().prevUntil("tr > td:nth-child(1)>input").css({"color":"red"});
</script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input></input>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21<input></input></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>click</span></td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that is in the last row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding is right then

```js
//dom ready handler
jQuery(function($) {
  $("span").click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll("tr:has(input)").first();
    alert($tr.index() + 1)
    $tr.css({
      "color": "red"
    });
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input/>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21<input/></td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>31</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>click</span></td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: THIS is the answer I have been looking for in the past 2 hours !